# Update CkEditor config on the basis of React state

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am using [CkEditor5](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5) for implementing CKEditor in my React application. I want to update the config wrt my state. But it seems like the editor component isn't updating even after the state change.
Here is my CKEditor component

```
<CKEditor
    editor={ ClassicEditor }
    data={this.state.content}
    onInit={ editor => {
        console.log( 'Editor is ready to use!', editor );
    } }
    config={{
      simpleUpload: {
      uploadUrl: uploadUrl,
      headers: {
          'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
      }
    }}}
    onChange={ ( event, editor ) => {
        const data = editor.getData();
        this.setState({
          content: data
        })
        console.log( { event, editor, data } );
    } }
    onBlur={ ( event, editor ) => {
        console.log( 'Blur.', editor );
    } }
    onFocus={ ( event, editor ) => {
        console.log( 'Focus.', editor );
    } }
/>
```

I want to update the upload URL based on the state.
It is stored in a variable like shown below -

```
const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
const uploadUrl = `https://example.com/api/blog/posts/images/${this.state.id}`
```

Comment: Have you gotten anywhere with this? having the same issue (vue proj), trying to change the language according to user selection, but find no way of changing the configuration after initial load.. going crazzzzy should be so simple !?

Comment: haven't found any solution yet, will have to raise an issue on GitHub i guess.

Comment: Please link to it here if you do, I've searched the docs, no mention of resetting any config options.. You would think an editor would have some setter methods for dynamic config options

Comment: ok, i'll raise an issue and if I find an answer I'll update here.

Comment: @webkit you can see the issue I posted [here](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-react/issues/132) It's not yet resolved. Please add your comment as well.

Comment: @webkit I've figured out the solution. Use the ClassicEditor instead of the CKEditor component. Check my answer below, for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using `ClassicEditor` instead of the `CKEditor` component.
I did this by writing two function for this. First `getEditorConfig` which would give me the changed config based on other parameters.

```
getEditorConfig = () => {
    const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
    const debug = window.location.hostname === "localhost" || window.location.hostname === "127.0.0.1"
    const uploadUrl = debug ? `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/blog/posts/images/${this.state.id}`
      : `https://example.com/api/blog/posts/images/${this.state.id}`

    return {
      simpleUpload: {
      uploadUrl: uploadUrl,
      headers: {
          'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
      }
    }}
  }
```

Next a helper function which creates a new editor instance and adds it to the DOM. I am storing the editor instance in the state.

```
  addEditor = () => {
    const config = this.getEditorConfig();

    ClassicEditor
      .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), config)
      .then(newEditor => this.setState({editor: newEditor}))
      .catch( error => {
          console.log( error );
      });
  }
```

In [one of the issues](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-react/issues/122) its suggested to destroy the old editor and create a new one when you want to update the config. So for that use the following two lines to destroy and use `addEditor` to create a new editor.

```
const { editor } =  this.state;
editor.destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution consists in adding ref and custom states to the editor e using a custom upload adapter. Now, I'm able to send the current state data to server and without using headers to that.

```
<CKEditor name="content" ref={editorRef}
            editor={Editor}
            config={customEditorConfig}
            data={article.content}

            customPropArticle={article}

            onReady={editor => {
                editor.editorRef = editorRef;
            }}
            onChange={onEditorChangeHandle}
        />
```

From UploadAdapter:

```
_sendRequest() {
    const editorRef = this.editor.editorRef;
    const { customPropArticle } = editorRef.current.props;
    
    this.loader.file.then(file => {
        const data = new FormData();

        data.append('id', customPropArticle.Id);
        data.append('upload', file);

        this.xhr.send(data);
    });
```